# How to partition a keyed RDD into 2 partitions based on its key value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

There is an RDD with vehicles data. I am able to get key-value pair of that RDD keeping LIC_state as key for every record.

How can I partition that keyed RDD into 2 partitions keeping records with key SA in one partition and the rest in another partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write and apply your custom partitioner that splits the data based on the key.

First define the partitioner logic

```py
def partitionFunc(key):
    if key == "SA":
        return 0
    else
        return 1
```

in which `key` is the "LIC_state". And then apply it to your `RDD`:

```py
partitionedRDD = keyedRDD.partitionBy(2, partitionFunc)
```

where `keyedRDD` is your key/value paired RDD.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I am doing" [partionedRDD.glom().collect()]"

Comment: and the error is:Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 22, 192-168-182-133.tpgi.com.au, executor driver): TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager)